# How to make AUCTeX aware of my custom sty files in an inner folder

Tags: auctex

Is it possible to point AUCTeX to extra *.sty files I load from an inner folder? Currently, I don't have access to environments defined e.g. in `amsmath`.

I realise the problem is AUCTeX does not seem to parse custom files in folders.
I created sub-folders to keep my project clean.
Currently, this is the structure:

```
root\
    setupfiles\
        packages.sty
        settings.sty
        definitions.sty
    main.tex
    % other tex files
```

All custom packages (my files) either load common packages such as `amsmath` or define some extra macros.
LaTeX finds everything but `AUCTeX` does not seem to see the files.

I understand I would solve the problem by moving everything back to the root folder.
However, I wonder if there is something I could let AUCTeX know about the files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the folder `setupfiles` to the list pointed to by `TeX-macro-private` whose documentation reads:

> Directories where you store your personal TeX macros.

Equally, `AUXTeX` should pick this up from the `TEXINPUTS` environment variable if you have set that.

Comment: Thanks. I chased the case and it turns out I also use a common sty file: `smallreport.sty`, which is located in `~/texmf/tex/latex/local/smallreport.sty`. It is where `amsmath` is loaded. I have `\usepackage{smallreport}` in master file but for some reason AUCTeX has not parsed this file by default. I had to run `TeX-auto-generate`, which created `smallreport.el` in the `<root>/auto/`. It is working now. However, I wonder if AUCTeX could do that automatically every time I run a new project that loads `smallreport.sty`.

Comment: Put `smallreport.el` in the folder pointed to by `TeX-style-private` and then it will be loaded whenever your TeX file loads `smallreport.sty`.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong because the last recommendation did not work. Thanks for suggestion :)